# Как сделать insert with update?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица `A(id, b_id, value)` в которой столбец `b_id` ссылается на столбец `id` таблицы `B(id, value)`. Раньше значение `value` хранилось в таблице `A`, но сейчас добавилась таблица `B` (она еще пустая) куда надо вставить записи и перенести данные. Я имею ввиду что я сделаю что-то вроде `insert into B (value) select value from A` и таким образом для каждой записи из таблицы `A` создам запись в таблице `B`, но я не знаю как записать при этом ссылку `A.b_id` на созданную запись. Разве что выполнять запрос откуда-то из php например и построчно вставлять в таблицу `B` и обновлять таблицу `A`. Нельзя ли это из mysql сделать как-то?

Comment: Если value уникально, то можно после insert найти все записи и проставить соответствующие им id. Если нет, то зависит от полноты переноса данных. если переносятся скажем все value один к одному, то можно сначала в A заполнить b_id порядковыми номерами, потом переписать в B все значения с уже готовыми id и установить на таблице B автоинкремент (если есть) на следующее значение после максимального вставленного id

Comment: @Mike value не уникально и переносятся все записи. А как из mysql заполнить b_id порядковыми номерами? Я пытался вот так, но не вышло: `set @index = 0;
update A
set @index = @index + 1
set b_id = @index;`

Comment: @Mike а, все, получилось: `set @index = 0; update A set b_id = (@index := @index + 1);`. Спасибо!